# Powering 3 micro stepping pumps simultaneously

Tags: stepper-motor, esp32, stepper-driver

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use three micro stepping motors that act as a peristaltic pump. I have no access to the data sheet, but the company we purchased them from has provided the seemingly crucial information which I will include below. The microcontroller is an ESP32 dev kit c4, and I am using three [STSPIN220](https://www.pololu.com/product/2876) breakout module from Pololu for the drivers, each containing one potentiometer to set the current limit (by adjusting VRef).

The goal of the project is to control three pumps simultaneously. I started with using a modification of the AccelStepper Library that I have created for readability. The software is functional, however I am having trouble with the circuit design. To ensure I had no issues with the code, I opted for connecting the step/dir pins of the three drivers in parallel (same results for my code using accelSteppers and when running the step pins in parallel).

Initially, I set the potentiometers so that the VRef can create an appropriate current for the motors (200mAmps requires a Vref of 40mV). Running a single driver/motor at a time, this works perfect and I see no issues.

My problem arises when I attempt to run 3 motors at once. They typically will not run right away. In order for me to get them going, I have to "tune" the potentiometers. I will increase/decrease the Vref via the potentiometers on one driver, and I get an effect on all three drivers. After going through and adjusting these potentiometers, the motors will run fine. However, if I turn off the power or change the rpm mid run, the driver potentiometers have to be re "tuned".

This leads me to believe it is something to do with the circuit design which I am not fully understanding. I have included two schematics, one is a breakdown of just the three driver boards, esp32, and how they receive their power.
The other one (which has had some modifications on the pin inputs to the driver boards) is the schematic of the full project. It contains a few more parts that I do not think play a role in the current issue, but I have included it just in case.

Additionally I am running it off a decent quality bench power supply at the moment, current limit at 3A. The circuit is also built onto a custom PCB breakout shield to mitigate any loose wires as the cause of the problem. Any and all suggestion help!

Stepper Motor Specs:

- Inductance Rating: 2.2 mH (REF. At 25°C 1 KHz, 1.0 Vrms (Each phase))
- Rated Voltage: 2.6 VDC
- Rated Current: around 200 mA at 2.6 VDC
- Type: 2-2 Phase exciting, bi-polar stepper motor
- Step angle: 0.349880 degrees
- Speed reduction ratio: 1:51.4462
- Pump can rotate: CW or CCW, but make sure the pump is completely
  stopped for 2-3 sec before changing the rotation direction.
- Resistance: 21 Ω +/-5% (at 25°C)
- Max starting pulse rate: 800 pps/min (constant voltage, no load)
- Max constant pulse rate: 1000 pps/min (same as above)

(Edit) - Files added below:

[image: Pump Power (Partial)]

Schematic - Pump Power (Partial)

[image: Takasago Proto Board]
Schematic - Takasago Proto Board

Update:

Thanks everyone for the continued support, I have been on a hiatus from this problem do to another project, but back at it.

I attempted to use three buck convertors as the Vmotor supply in an attempt to isolate any sort of frequency on the power lines, and did not notice a difference in doing so. I also increased the Vmotor power supply up to the limit of the STSPIN220 breakout module and did not notice a difference. I then attempted to use the buck convertors on the V logic lines and still nothing.

I decided the next step was an updated driver. Many suggestions (on a few different forums) suggested to use a driver that has a magnitude of voltage input greater than needed to power the stepper as to ensure it can create the needed current, and as such I have upgraded.

Currently still am unsuccessful at running three motors/drivers at once. I have recently acquired three TMC2209 stepper breakout drivers from watterott to replace the Pololu STSPIN220s. The reason I chose these was hopefully in the future (if I get everything working) I can free up some pins using the UART control. As of right now, I am using standard configuration as to be a "drop in replacement".

The new drivers will allow a 12 V input, and I have modified my design to accommodate (No more linear voltage regulators between the Vmotor pin and PSU. The PSU runs the Vmotor powerlines in parallel with a few caps near the driver). The schematic remains essentially the same.
I am still running into the same issue though.
I can control one driver perfectly fine, no issues (doesn't matter what driver or motor, as long as only one driver is running). As soon as I try and run more than one driver, I get the sporadic  results noticed on the STSPIN220.

I have also gone and rewired the circuit on a bread board (I know this can cause loose connections on the signals), just in case, and still had identical results to the PCB breakout board I made.

I'm inclined to believe that the issue is hardware related, and I am missing an essential component in filtering either signal/power lines headed to/from the driver.

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE. You should include images directly in your answer, as it makes them easier to look at while typing answers/comments. You are going to need to improve your schematics, as currently, the Takkasago one is totally unreadable. Use labels like you have for you power lines, and consider using power flags for your power lines. I also dont see any POTs, and maybe add some text to explain things. Make it as easy for people to understand as you can, so more people look at it.

Comment: On your first schematic there is a 12V input connected to the regulator U3, but there seems to be no 12V connections visible going to the similar U1 or U2 regulators, is there a connection missing on the schematic? (The inputs to U1 and U2 are actually connected to GND instead of the 12V).

Comment: @Dave K , the schematic files you referenced have been added into your question.  Edit the captions further if needed.  (If you need to edit the drawings save them as JPG then upload.)

Comment: @DaveK Is the circuit built on a PCB or on a breadboard?